# Paypal SDK REST API - Can I trust from paypal response the invoice_number and total?

Tags: php, paypal

Is safe to trust `invoice_number` and `total` from `$payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get($paymentId, $apiContext);` or it could be manipulated by user? Obviously when the `state` is `approved`, which I assume is when the payment was successfully concluded.

Comment: I would imagine this is something you will have to answer yourself because it largely (or even wholly) depends on _how you implement_ (any) API...

Comment: @EdSF Maybe I was not clear. For example, users can manipulated (or maybe it better to say edit) the shipping informations using paypal interface.  What about total and invoice_number?